# How clean inside range hood, over fans?

Tags: range

[image]

My Toronto, CA condo has [Sakura R727II range hood](http://www.sakura-canada.com/SakuraProduct1.html). I screen capped page 7 in [Installation Guide](https://www.trailappliances.com/media/wysiwyg/PDFs/guides/Sakura_Hoodfans_09162013_R74730WII_2.pdf). I bought 7 years ago, and never cleaned inside! When I sear or pan fry some things, I smell much smoke now!

Much smoke means grease clogging fans and exhaust duct. Right?

Undeniably I can't see or reach over fan inside range hood! How can I clean? Easy to remove range hood? Or I need technician? Is there profession called "range hood technician"?

[image]

Comment: North? What does that mean?

Comment: ""range hood technician""? not that I know of but there is "jack of all trades" aka handyman.

Answer (score 1):

I would start out by thoroughly cleaning the fan housing and blades. Most of the grease you're referring to will be on the blades and will really cut down on their efficiency. So remove that grease and you'll see a big difference. Anything more than that will require removing the hood.
If you have access to the area above the hood, like a cabinet or attic, you can disassemble the vent pipes and clean them. Just make sure to re assemble them correctly.