# Can I clean range hood exhaust duct without reaching it?

Tags: range

1. My home range hood is [Sakura R-727II](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/185676). Plz see pictures that post. I never clean [my range hood's EXHAUST DUCT 7 years after buying](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/182604/68433). It's probably greasy and clogged. 
   How can I clean it, but not access it? I don't want remove range hood or open exhaust duct. I see no Access Panel like picture below.
2. Are there safe chemicals I can spray at range hood? Then when I turn on range hood fans, these chemicals suck into exhaust duct, destroy grease?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How clean inside range hood, over fans?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182604/how-clean-inside-range-hood-over-fans)

Comment: Buy a new one or get a handyman.

Comment: hydrogen dioxide works well. Blast it with steam, which will melt the old grease and cause it to drip out.

Comment: Do NOT use oven cleaner.  It will remove the paint.

Comment: You have changed the photo to a,commercial/industrial range hood and duct with exhaust fan, image. **How is that relevant to your home kitchen range hood that is not a commercial/industrial range hood and duct with exhaust fan ?**.

Comment: @AlaskaMan sorry! i didn't know that pic is INDUSTRIAL range hood! i just wanted explain my HOME kitchen range hood don't have Access Panels. i thought HOME kitchen range hoods have access panels!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How remove Sakura R-727II to clean inside?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185676/how-remove-sakura-r-727ii-to-clean-inside)

Comment: @SolarMike No! im asking how clean RANGE HOOD. there. here i ask how clean EXHAUST DUCT. RANGE HOOD not EXHAUST DUCT!

Comment: Personally I think you should get a contractor.

Answer (score 3):

*Exhaust duct is greasy clogged, right?*  - **We do not know, we can not see it from here.**

*How can I clean it, but not access it?* - **You can not. You have to access the duct if you want to clean it.**

*Are there safe chemicals I can spray at range hood fans?* - **There are dozens of safe grease cutting/cleaning chemicals on the market.**

*Then when I turn on range hood fans, these chemicals suck into exhaust duct, destroy all grease, and everything sucked out?* - **NO, that is not how it works. There is no sucking mechanism in your duct.**

*I don't want remove range hood or open exhaust duct.* - **Sorry but removal of the hood is required to clean the duct ( and to even assess if it is indeed full of grease.)**

Here is the [USA distributors web site](http://sakura-usa.com/). Your model is the R-727II.

Here is the contact email for sakura USA -  achoo@sakura-usa.com

Here is  [link to  a search results](https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=mAEB&search_query=how%20to%20clean%20the%20sakura%20R-727II%20range%20hood) on YouTube for cleaning range hoods.

*Your unit does appear to be rather unconventional, looking at the photo it is not clear where the filters are or how to access them.*

**That is why you need to contact them directly.**

**UPDATE:** *Your range hood does not have "traditional" screens that trap the grease. There are two clear plastic grease collectors for each fan. one is mounted to the cone shaped fan guard and the other is at the back of the unit behind each fan near the wall. I believe the premise is condenses or collects on some unknown to me part of the unit and then drips down into the removable plastic receptacles. In theory the grease should not be getting into your duct. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFZZSkxHk4o), not in English shows a brief simulation of the grease trap at work near the end of the video. [Here is link](https://mkt.com/sakurausa) to a parts page that has the plastic trays.*

Please send me your gratitude in the form of a quality **local craft beer** from the area of your region. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest to get a new hood fan. 
But here with this hood fan the problem is there is no screen to retain the grease and filter it  before reaching the dock.

You have 2 plastic container to manage the grease a little, but still a lot is going into your dock.

I am pretty sure also this fan at 7 years, is having a lot of grease in both fan area and start making noise. The power is reduced also because it's very greasy in there.

You could even buy a used one in very good condition with way more efficiency.

---

#### The other option :

On the other side, you could get some brake cleaner and spray it. If you really wish do to this.
I would close the electrical breaker that give power to this hood fan, and spray it enough. You should wait couple of hours and remove the cap under the fan that we see on the picture you provided, to remove the collected grease, and do the same with the two plastic container in the back. Clean them and put them back on. Open up back the  breaker in the electrical panel and start up the fan to see if there is it still work good.

I still highly suggest you to get a new one. Time for a little bonus in the kitchen!