# How remove Sakura R-727II range hood to clean inside?

Tags: cleaning, range

I don't know how range hood is fixed under panel. By way, what do you call this fixation under panel?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: **Have you tried to remove the screws around the perimeter  on the underside ?** I would think this would give you access to the mounting system inside the unit. Typically it is just four screws holding  it to the cabinet. ( *your unit is not typical* )

Comment: Please don't rollback the edit that removed the contact details that you've tried. It was edited by a mod, and with good reason; there's no need for that information in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation manual](https://www.trailappliances.com/media/wysiwyg/PDFs/guides/Sakura_Hoodfans_09162013_R74730WII_2.pdf) appears to have all the information you will need to uninstall the hood for cleaning. Although I'm not sure why you would need to completely uninstall this hood in order to clean it.
However, if that's necessary just follow the installation instructions in reverse starting with removing the bottom panel to access the four mounting screws at the inside top of the hood. These screws have keyhole openings and only need to be loosened to slide the unit forward. Be sure to turn off the power before attempting to remove any electrical connections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove the under panel to clean inside for this particular model. The only removable parts that you can remove for routine clean job are the two vane guard the the two oil collectors.